# What's an idiomatic way to end an invitation in English?

Tags: idiomatic-language, greetings, emphasis

In my native language, the most natural way to end an invitation of any kind (to a party, to first day of school, to a meeting, to a knitting course – whatever) is to write "Varmt välkommen!" – literally 'Warmly welcome!'. Of course, this doesn't work in English, but what would be an idiomatic equivalent? I realize that "Welcome!" on it's own would work, but if I don't think that's enthusiastic enough, what could I use instead?

Would "A warm welcome to you all!" work? Or is there some other way I could phrase it, so that I use "welcome", but with more emphasis, as it were?

Comment: In English generally, invitations don't have any greeting at the end like that. Sorry, but it's just not done. If you do that, it will probably be viewed as somewhat odd/strange.

Comment: You could always add something like: **Hope to see you there** or **Hope you can make it**

Comment: @BillyKerr Huh? Really? Does that go for all kinds of invitations, not only invitations to parties? So, for instance, if Mrs Smith, who is a teacher, invites all the parents to a parents' meeting, she wouldn't write any kind of welcome/greeting at the end?? Or if a teacher at the university writes an info letter welcoming new students to a new semester, they wouldn't have a greeting at the end??

Comment: @RonaldSole Yes, or perhaps "Looking forward to seeing you"? But is there nothing (except just "welcome") that includes the sense that I'm welcoming the people I'm inviting?

Comment: We welcome the people when they arrive at the event, not in advance!

Comment: Yes, really, and yes for all types of invitation.  If an invitation is very informal then just about anything goes, however "welcome" seems very odd.  "Welcome" is generally used when people arrive at a party, not before. It just doesn't work, even on an informal invitation. Traditionally, formal invites don't have anything like that. Just leave it out. Nobody will think it's rude.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you! This is truly interesting – I had no idea! Thank you so much for clearing this up for me!

Comment: @BillyKerr By the way, I hope you didn't take my "Huh? Really?" the wrong way - I didn't mean it in a rude way, just as an expression of my surprise :)

Comment: @Lillatanten - no worries!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, baqcked by several versions of *Miss Manners's Guide* invitations in English, at least in US and UK English, simply do not use any "welcoming close
or indeed any closing at all (I don't count RSVP as a closing). Very informal invitations might enf with "Hope to see yum there" or something similar. Formal invitations do not. Formal invitations are very standardized.

By the way, the usual translation of RSVP for formal, third-person invitations is:

> The favor of a reply is requested.

Comment: Thank you! Does this go for all kinds of invitations though, not only invitations to parties and the like? So, for instance, if Mrs Smith, who is a teacher, invites all the parents to a parents' meeting, she wouldn't write any kind of welcome/greeting at the end? Or if a teacher at the university writes an info letter welcoming new students to a new semester, they wouldn't have a greeting at the end?

Comment: Yes. Formal invitations never use a welcome or greeting at the end for any kind of invitation. Very casual ones **might** use something like "I hope to see you there", but most do not. If an invitation is conveyed in a letter, the ordinary closing for a letter would be used.

Comment: Thanks again! This is kinda mind blowing haha :))

Answer (score 2):

There is a formulaic way to end an invitation: "RSVP". This is an abbreviation of the French *Répondez s'il vous plaît* and it means "please reply" - or literally "reply, if it pleases you".

So a typical invite might look something like

```
 You're Invited!
       to
 Johan's Party
       on
Monday 16th June
      from
    7:30 pm
       at
 Johan's house.

      RSVP
  by 9th June
```

Looking at other kinds of invitations, when I wrote to invite parents of my class to a meeting I used a semi-formal letter style for my email I began with a paragraph stating "You are invited" and giving place and time. The rest of the email was taken up with agenda items. And I closed with a "Best Regards" (and my email signature).

I would not consider the letter giving induction information on the first day of school to be an "invitation". But I would use a similar semi-formal letter style, and close with "Best Regards" or "Yours Sincerely".

The knitting course - again its not an invitation; it is an advert. There is no particular way to end an advertisment.

Comment: Thank you – this is something else entirely though, corresponding to O.S.A in my own language. It would be very odd (and kinda rude) to use this as a **substitute** for the greeting at the end of a message/an invitation, wouldn't it? (And also, RSVP/O.S.A. is only used with a small subset of invitations).

Comment: *Répondez s'il vous plaît*

Comment: +1 but just corrected the spelling, and the translation.  Also remember that "invite" is the verb - but the noun is "invitation". "Invite" has undoubtedly claimed noun status - but never in my house!

Comment: It means something entirely different, but it is the idiomatic way to end an invitation in English. Try a google image search for "invitation" and you'll see lots of templates for invitations.  They don't end with anything like "welcome" or "A warm welcome to you all" they end with RSVP.  It is the formulaic way to end invitations. @Lillatanten

Comment: @WS2 - [according to the OED](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00120691), in colloquial English, invite is also a noun and a synonym for "an invitation".

Comment: @BillyKerr That was why I said that "invite" has "claimed noun status, but not in my house". We are allowed to speak the language of our choice in our own houses aren't we?